# My app named store does not get recognized to migrate

Tags: python, django

When migrating, my app 'store' is not recognized. It is already installed inside `settings.py` but the migration command `python manage.py makemigrations store` fails with the error: "No installed app with label 'store'"

```py
# ./core/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'store',
]
```

When migrating, the `_0001_initial.py` file was also not created automatically under migrations.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the `store` app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting correctly. It should take this format:

```py
# ./core/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
    ....
]
```

You must also define `StoreConfig`. However, this should be here be default after you ran the `startapp` command in your terminal to create the app:

```py
# ./store/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class StoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'store'
```

Take a look at the Django tutorial in the documentation which covers [creating apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app) and [activating models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) for more info.

Hope this helps!